# Remembering the address of the calling page of a form (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a little module that implements hook_menu and when the menu item is selected it displays a form that is defined as so:

```
function documentation_menu_nameform() {

  $form['documentation'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#title' => t('Documentation'),
    '#default_value' => 'This project has not been documented.',
    '#format' => NULL,
    '#weight' => 0,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit')
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Now when this menu item is selected it brings up a form at the address ?q=documentation_menu and in my form submission hook I would like to return to the page the user was on before they selected the menu item but I can't figure out how to access and/or store this path.

Comment: this is a job for drupal_get_destination()   http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/7

Comment: @Jimajamma You should put that as the answer with a small example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this like so:

Have your menu item URL generated with destination parameter, for example:

/?q=documentation_menu&destination=some/path/where/user/had/just/been

add a hidden field to your form and populate it with destination path

```
$form['destination'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#value' => drupal_get_destination()
);
```

if you for some reasons can't add destination parameter to that URL, then you'll need to extract that URL from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] and populate hidden field with it.

Then in your submit function just do a redirect to the path specified in that hidden field:

```
function documentation_menu_nameform_submit() {
  ...

  drupal_goto($_POST['destination']);
}
```